# C# screen recorder not merging audio

Tags: c#, audio, screen-recording

I'm currently trying to make a screen recorder in C#. Right now I have it where the video file and audio files are both successfully made, but I can't figure out how to merge them. This is what I have so far:

```
public void Stop()
        {
            int width = bounds.Width;
            int height = bounds.Height;

            var framRate = 30;

            //Save audio:
            string audioPath = "save recsound " + outputPath + "\\mic.wav";
            record(audioPath, "", 0, 0);
            record("close recsound", "", 0, 0);

            using (var vFWriter = new VideoFileWriter())
            {
                //Create new video file:
                vFWriter.Open(outputPath + "//video.mp4", width, height, framRate, VideoCodec.MPEG4);

                //Make each screenshot into a video frame:
                foreach (var imageLocation in inputImageSequence)
                {
                    Bitmap imageFrame = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageLocation) as Bitmap;
                    vFWriter.WriteVideoFrame(imageFrame);
                    imageFrame.Dispose();
                }

                //Add audio:
                byte[] audioByte = File.ReadAllBytes(outputPath + "\\mic.wav");
                vFWriter.WriteAudioFrame(audioByte);

                //Close:
                vFWriter.Close();
            }
            //Delete the screenshots and temporary folder:
            DeletePath(tempPath);
        }
```

I don't get any errors, however the audio just isn't being added to the `video.mp4`. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It depends on the library you use. Where comes `VideoFileWriter`from?

Comment: It comes from `using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;`

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know this framework, but I found [this examples](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Accord.DirectSound/AudioCaptureDevice/-/php-audiocapturedevice-class-examples.html). Maybe that will help.

Comment: Getting the audio isn't the problem. I just need to find a way to combine the audio and video files once I have both of them.

Comment: I know, but you write, you could call `WriteAudioFrame` without any error, but it does not write the audio. Did you have a look to the initialization in the example: `videoWriter.Open(OutputPath, width, height, framerate, VideoCodec.H264, videoBitRate,
                    AudioCodec.MP3, audioBitRate, audioDevice.SampleRate, audioDevice.Channels);`